# Why is setSize method necessary to show scroll on Composite in SWT?

Tags: java, swt, scrolledcomposite

I'm working on to create UI with JAVA SWT.

One thing makes me confused with using ScrolledComposite.
Why my code does not show a scroll without setting the MinSize of Composite?

Can anyone explain what setMinSize does in ScrolledComposite?

Why can't we use **"setSize"** insetead of **"setMinSize"**?

Below is my code.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;


public class MyPractice {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    final ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    sc.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

    Composite c = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(7, true));
    c.setBackground(new Color(display, 0,255,0));

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
      Button b = new Button(c, SWT.PUSH);
      b.setText("Button " + i);
    }

    sc.setContent(c);
    sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    sc.setExpandVertical(true);


    //*****Why is this code necessary to get Scroll on UI?
    sc.setMinSize(c.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

    //Why can't we use "setSize" insetead of setMinSize? setSize does not show scroll. 
    //sc.setSize(c.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));


    shell.setSize(300, 500);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();

}
}
```

Comment: Why does it bother you that you have to call `setMinSize()` instead of `setSize()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setSize()` and `setMinSize()` are two very different functions. `Control#setSize()` sets the actual size of a `Control` whereas `ScrolledComposite#setMinSize()` is specific to `ScrolledComposite` and tells it at which size to start showing the scroll bars:

> Specify the minimum width and height at which the `ScrolledComposite` will begin scrolling the content with the horizontal scroll bar. This value is only relevant if `setExpandHorizontal(true)` and `setExpandVertical(true)` have been set.

The minimum size of the scrolled composite will be based on the size of the child.

Comment: You gave me a big clue, I think I can apply it to what I'm doing. thanks!!